# Widget is not rebuilding when it should

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

so I have a `PopUpMenuButton` which has some choices,

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.tune,
      color: FortBuddyTheme.grey,
      size: 24,
    ),
    color: Colors.white,
    onCanceled: () {},
    onSelected: (int value) {
      if (selectedChart == 0) {
        setState(() {
          playlist = 'p2';
          name = 'Solo';
          color = 0xff4af699;
        });
      } else if (selectedChart == 1) {
        setState(() {
          playlist = 'p10';
          name = 'Duo';
          color = 0xFFA29BFE;
        });
      } else if (selectedChart == 2) {
        setState(() {
          playlist = 'p9';
          name = 'Squad';
          color = 0xFF0984E3;
        });
      }
    },
    itemBuilder: (_) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          'Show Solos Chart',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily:
                FortBuddyTheme.fontName,
            fontSize: 16,
            letterSpacing: 0.5,
            height: 0.9,
            color:
                FortBuddyTheme.darkerText,
          ),
        ),
        value: 0,
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          'Show Duos Chart',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily:
                FortBuddyTheme.fontName,
            fontSize: 16,
            letterSpacing: 0.5,
            height: 0.9,
            color:
                FortBuddyTheme.darkerText,
          ),
        ),
        value: 1,
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          'Show Squad Chart',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily:
                FortBuddyTheme.fontName,
            fontSize: 16,
            letterSpacing: 0.5,
            height: 0.9,
            color:
                FortBuddyTheme.darkerText,
          ),
        ),
        value: 2,
      ),
    ],
  )),
```

It has a few `if` statements which check and set some variables, those variables are used by a widget, but even if the variables change under `setState`, the widget is not rebuilding.
(widget)

```dart
MainContainer(
        animation: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController,
            curve:
                Interval((1 / count) * 3, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))),
        animationController: animationController,
        title: name,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        child: LineChartSample1(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          playlist: playlist,
          title: '$name' + 's',
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
```

Also note, the widget is being added through a `addAllListData()` function which adds all the widgets to a list, that list later gets build by a builder method.

Comment: Which widget are you expecting to rebuild?

Comment: The `MainContainer` widget

Comment: Where is the `PopupMenuButton` inside the `MainContainer` widget?

Comment: They are not in the same widget

Comment: Well, there's your problem. `setState` will only rebuild the widget that it's called on. If the button and the container are in completely separate widgets, chances are the rebuild triggered by the button isn't affecting the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statements, use `value` instead of `selectedChart`. Like this:

```
if (value == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (selectedChart == 0)
```

Comment: I switched it, it did not rebuild still.